# Hot to get last modified credit memo record from netsuite

Tags: java, web-services, netsuite

I am using Java and NetSuite webserivces to get the last modified credit memo transactions or refund transactions for all customers but there is no any kind of searchBasic class to do it. If anyone done it before then please provide your suggestion or absolute answer as I am new to netsuite I don't know all the thing.

If you know about the balance rather than credit memo then also it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<CreditMemo> searchRecentCreditMemos()
        throws Exception {
    TransactionSearch transactionsSearch = new TransactionSearch();
    TransactionSearchBasic transactionSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    CustomerSearchBasic custSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();

    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Create criteria
    com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2014_1.SearchDateField searchDateField = new com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2014_1.SearchDateField();
    searchDateField
            .setOperator(com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2014_1.types.SearchDateFieldOperator.within);
    searchDateField.setSearchValue(startDate);
    searchDateField.setSearchValue2(endDate);

    transactionSearchBasic.setLastModifiedDate(searchDateField);

    transactionsSearch.setBasic(transactionSearchBasic);
    transactionsSearch.setCustomerJoin(custSearchBasic);

    SearchResult result = port.search(transactionsSearch);
    ArrayList<CreditMemo> creditMemoList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (result.getStatus().isIsSuccess()) {
        RecordList recordList = result.getRecordList();
        Record[] records = recordList.getRecord();

        if (records != null && records.length != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
                if (records[i] instanceof CreditMemo) {
                    CreditMemo creditMemo = (CreditMemo) records[i];
                    creditMemoList.add(creditMemo);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return creditMemoList;
}
```